# Error en vista laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, programación-móvil, livewire

Cuando entro desde el celular se crashea la vista, y al ir actualizando se ve cada vez peor, me pasa solo en una vista que se llama etiquetas y la otra dashboard

Revise todo y no faltan comillas ni nada por el estilo

Esto es un listado de tags, y al solo entrar se crashea así, en otra vista de listado de productos no pasa, se ve re bien

Saben que puede ser?? También me pasa desde chromo y por ejemplo desde Firefox no, hablando siempre desde el celular

[image: ver imagen 1]

[image: ver imagen 2]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.